# Duplicity error pop-up on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, duplicity

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm getting an error message that pops up quite often saying, "Could not understand duplicity version".

I tried using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` but in vain.

[image: Error]

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Can you add a screenshot to the question?

Comment: Sure, I've added it now. 

Here's the link.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/5zoj3.png

Comment: I've reinstalled Linux now and I'm able to backup. I had installed a lot of programs earlier on and some of them were not done properly which is probably why I was getting this error.

Comment: Anyone find a resolve for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It seems a python error. Try to change start script
`$ sudo vi /usr/bin/duplicity`
and change the first from: 
`#! /usr/bin/python`
to
`#! /usr/bin/python2`

Answer (score 1):

You can diagnose some of the problem from the command line with:

```
duplicity --version
```

You will likely get a Python import error.
You can try to install the missing package mentioned with

```
pip install the_package
```

For me, I got `ImportError: No module named duplicity`, but installing from pip didn't work.

I also tried:

```
sudo apt remove duplicity
sudo apt install duplicity
```

but that didn't work for me either.

In the end I traced it down to a custom virtualenv command I had added to my `~/.profile` file, which ultimately modified the `$PATH` and must have meant that duplicity wasn't running under the system version of Python.

Check

```
$ echo $PATH
```

for a path that might have an alternate version of the Python executable.

Removing that call to `source ~/.virtualenvs/customve/bin/activate` from `~/.profile` and rebooting fixed it for me.

Note: that custom virtualenv activation command was fine in Ubuntu 14.04, possibly because that distribution was on an older version of Python so there was no confusion?