# Backup Failed: Could not understand duplicity version

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I am trying to perform backup on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, i get the following error.

Tried googling the issue, could not find any working solution.[image]

How to rectify this issue ?

P.S. I have referred to this link also. [Duplicity error pop-up on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818249/duplicity-error-pop-up-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` then `sudo apt-get autoremove` then `sudo apt-get install -f` and finally `sudo reboot`.

Comment: penta did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @edlee, nope...tried all tricks, none worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicity error pop-up on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818249/duplicity-error-pop-up-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove duplicity
sudo apt-get install duplicity
```

Or run `duplicity --version` and install the missing packages.

Comment: Have the same issue as above. When I run --version or anything else, I get this message.

duplicity --help   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 45, in <module>
    from lockfile import LockFile as FileLock
ImportError: No module named lockfile

Comment: Run `pip install lockfile` ?

Comment: That got it working. THANKS!!!  

And, I know how it happened  also -- I cleaned out the global Pip packages I could identify, Ha-ha! After upgrading to 16.04, I managed to leaked some packages out of my virtualenv. So it got spring-cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need additional packages that are missing.
I encountered the same issue once I reinstalled the Python.

```
$ pip install lockfile duplicity PyGObject
```

Make sure proper(which relates to Python that duplicity uses) pip is used if you use multiple versions of Python.

After you have installed the packages you might be able to ensure duplicity is running properly.

```
$ duplicity --version
duplicity 0.7.14
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was caused because duplicity assumes that you are running python 2.X. I use python 3 - and had the link 'python' in /usr/bin pointing to a python 3 version. Removing that link and creating one that pointed to a python 2 solved the problem.